# Riemannian Geometry Gauss equation proof

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm having some problem understanding some steps in a proof of the Gauss equation in Riemannian Geometry. I'm not writing down the whole proof, just the parts I'm having problem with understanding. Here, $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold and $N$ is a submanifold with the induced metric. $X,Y,Z,W\in C^\infty(TM)$ are vector fields, $[\,\cdot\,]$ denotes the Lie bracket, $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection of $M$ and $\perp$ and $\top$ denote the normal and tangential part of an orthogonal decomposition, respectively.

The first step I'm having problem with understanding is the following:

$g((\nabla_X(\nabla_YZ-(\nabla_YZ)^\perp))^\top-(\nabla_Y(\nabla_XZ-(\nabla_XZ)^\perp))^\top,W)-g((\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z-(\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z)^\perp)^\top,W)=g(\nabla_X\nabla_YZ-\nabla_Y\nabla_XZ-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z,W)-g(\nabla_X(\nabla_YZ)^\perp,W)+g(\nabla_Y(\nabla_XZ)^\perp,W)$

Here it seems like, for example, $(\nabla_X(\nabla_YZ)^\perp)^\top=\nabla_X(\nabla_YZ)^\perp$ Could someone explain why that is? Also, it seems like $((\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z)^\perp)^\top=0$. Why is that?

In the next step,

$-g(\nabla_X(\nabla_YZ)^\perp,W)+g(\nabla_Y(\nabla_XZ)^\perp,W)=g((\nabla_YZ)^\perp,(\nabla_XW)^\perp)-g((\nabla_XZ)^\perp,(\nabla_YW)^\perp)$

is being used. Does anyone know where this comes from? My guess is that it has something to do with the fact that the Levi-Civita connection is compatible with the Riemannian metric.

Comment: No time to write a full answer, but: $((\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z)^{\perp})^\top = 0$ because the tangent component of a normal vector is zero. And in the last thing in display, compatibility is being used: $X(g((\nabla_YZ)^\perp,W))=0$ because you already have $g((\nabla_YZ)^\perp,W)=0$, as one vector is normal and the other is tangent.

Comment: Thank you! So $(\nabla_X(\nabla_YZ)^\perp)^\top=\nabla_X(\nabla_YZ)^\perp$ because $\nabla_Z:C^\infty (TM)\rightarrow C^\infty (TM)$? I know that $(\nabla_YZ)^\perp$ is a section of the normal bundle of $N$, but this also makes it a part of $C^\infty (TM)$.

Comment: That was the only thing unclear to me. People always use different symbols for the Levi-Civita connections of $M$ and $N$. You didn't, so I don't know how to answer. My previous comment was an educated guess, to be honest.

Comment: Ah, sorry. $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection of $M$. If we denote the Levi-Civita connection of $N$ by $\bar{\nabla}$, let $\bar{X},\bar{Y}\in C^\infty(TN)$ and $X,Y$ be two extensions, then $\bar{\nabla}_{\bar{X}}\bar{Y}=(\nabla_XY)^\top$ and $B(\bar{X},\bar{Y})=(\nabla_XY)^\perp$ (the second fundamental form of $N$ in $(M,g)$).